# Mobile bootstrap menu showing horizontal scrollbar

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently developing a Wordpress website using Bootstrap 3. For the navigation menu, I am using wp_bootstrap_navwalker. When I shorten the window width, I get the picture below:

[image: horizontal scrollbar showing in toggled menu]

The mobile menu has a horizontal scrollbar. In addition, the menu is pushed to full width so it hangs right on the edge of the menu. In the Bootstrap menu demo, the menu links are indented.

Here is my navbar code:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/UCHURCH.png"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'menu'              => 'header-menu',
                        'theme_location'    => 'header-menu',
                        'depth'             => 2,
                        'container'         => 'div',
                        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );
                ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

When I remove the wp_nav_menu and hardcode links, this is no longer an issue. So I know it has to do with the wp_nav_menu and the wp_bootstrap_navwalker. Can someone help me figure out how to make this horizontal scrollbar go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
.header-menu{width:100%; margin:0 auto}
```

or

```
.navbar-collapse{overflow-x:hidden}
```

Comment: The .navbar-collapse worked, I added it to the bootstrap css file. In addition, I had to add a padding-left to the .navbar-nav > li > a in order for the menu to be indented. But it works. Thanks!